# Using class or object to set limit on object property and trigger new object creation

Tags: javascript, class, logic

I have a profile with a number of fields that I need to generate a schema for.

The schema is a "vertical object" that I want to populate with a series of "horizontal objects". The "horizontal objects" contain the profile fields. I need to set a limit to the length of an array inside the "horizontal object" that will cause a new "horizontal object" to be generated and attached to the "vertical object" when the limit is reached:

```
allProfiles.forEach(profile => {
  var verticalObject = {
    type: "VerticalLayout",
    elements: []
  }

  var horizontalObject = {
    type: "HorizontalLayout",
    elements: []
  }

  profile.fields.forEach(field => {
    if(horizontalObject.elements.length < 2){
      horizontalObject.elements.push(field)
    }else{
      verticalObject.elements.push(horizontalObject)
      //generate new horizontal object and repeat until all fields are iterated through
    }

return verticalObject;
});
```

Should I be using a class for the horizontal object?

Answer (score 0):

I see a terminology problem here. I'm going to use different words that I think are more commonly used.

So you have a list of Profiles, and you want to show the list as a matrix with a set number of columns and a variable number of rows.

What the solution is depends on exactly why you need the matrix. If you just want to show it in a table: make a function that accepts a list and a `numColumns` and return a 2d dimensional array, and then render that.

If this is going into some underlying datamodel you need to think about how operations work on the matrix. What happens if you delete an element somewhere? Does it make a hole, does it shift elements to fill the hole?

Based on your question it's unclear what you need exactly but hopefully you can use this to find what you need.